# How do I fill in the gap between multiple CDF plots in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting multiple CDF plots in python using this code:

```
count, bins_count = np.histogram(np.log10(my_array), bins=100)

#Finding the pdf for the histogram 
pdf = count / sum(count)
                    
#Calculating the cdf
cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)
                    
plt.plot(bins_count[1:], cdf, color='g')
```

I am repeating this multiple times in a loop and putting them all on a single graph. I need to shade in the region between that these CDF plots span. How would I go about doing this?

I am using matplotlib to plot the graphs.

If anyone needs any more classification please let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `plt.fill_between`

Answer (score 0):

One could draw all the curves on top of each other, using some alpha value. That will generate something resembling a fill; the spots where more curves coincide will be darker.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for _ in range(100):
     data = 10 ** np.random.randn(10, 1000).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()
     count, bin_edges = np.histogram(np.log10(data), bins=100)
     # Finding the pdf for the histogram
     pdf = count / sum(count)
     # Calculating the cdf
     cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)
     plt.plot(bin_edges[1:], cdf, color='g', alpha=0.1)
```

Another approach uses `fill_between`. This needs a common x-axis. Therefore, the example code below works with fixed bins and calculates the overall minimum and maximum curves.

```py
min_curve = 1
max_curve = 0
for _ in range(100):
     bin_edges = np.linspace(-80, 80, 500)
     data = 10 ** np.random.randn(10, 1000).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()
     count, _ = np.histogram(np.log10(data), bins=bin_edges)
     # Finding the pdf for the histogram
     pdf = count / sum(count)
     # Calculating the cdf
     cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)
     min_curve = np.minimum(min_curve, cdf)
     max_curve = np.maximum(max_curve, cdf)
plt.fill_between(bin_edges[1:], min_curve, max_curve, color='g', alpha=0.3)
```

[image: combining many cdfs]